# Type Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type FutureOr<List<Status>>

Tags: flutter

I need your help.. 
I have a list with `CheckboxListTile`. If I checked or unchecked a item, the list reload. So I tried it with an `AsyncMemoizer`.

Now the following error is returned: '`Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Future<List<Status>>'`

Maybe you have other ideas as I can solve the problem with the list differently

```
final AsyncMemoizer _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
Future<List<Status>> fetchPost(){

  return _memoizer.runOnce(() async {
   final response =
      await http.get(URL);

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {    
        List<Status> tmp = Status.fromJsonList(json.decode(response.body));
        return tmp;
     } else {    
        throw Exception('Failed to load post');
     }

   });
}
static List<Status>  fromJsonList(List<dynamic> json) {
    List<Status> ret = new List<Status>();

    for (int i=0;i<json.length;i++){
      Status itm = Status(
      id: json[i]['I'],
      geschlecht: json[i]['G'],
      adresse: json[i]['A'],
      name: json[i]['AZ'], 
      //Checkbox
      isSelected : isValueChange(i)
      );

      ret.add(itm);
    }    
    return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you using memoizer, can you explain more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell your `AsyncMemoizer` what type to expect:

```
final AsyncMemoizer<List<Status>> _memoizer = AsyncMemoizer<List<Status>>();
```

Comment: you save my day bro!

Comment: I know i am too late but i am crying from joy, thank you very much!!! :)